# How can I send data as a POST with a JSON body, and navigate to the response?

Tags: javascript, html, http

I would like to send data using the POST method, have the body be a JSON object rather than a set of key-value pairs, and on success navigate to the response.

If I just wanted to send data with POST and navigate to the response, I would use a form.  If I just wanted to send a JSON with POST, I could use AJAX.  But is there any way to fit both criteria?

Comment: Navigate to the response meaning the content in the browser is replaced with the returned JSON?

Comment: You can use jQuery, post the JSON to the server via `$.ajax`, and on success you can set window.location = "somewhere" to load a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. The closest options you are have are to use Ajax and then:

- Use `history.pushState` to change the URL and replace the entire DOM with the response.
- Have the server store the result somewhere and then return a URL in the response that the JavaScript could then assign to `location.href`. The URL would have a token that the browser could use to get the stored response.

Comment: IE9 will fail in this case, no support of history.pushState.

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven: True. It's also an obsolete browser [with 1.1% of the global market share](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) and an upgrade path without OS upgrade to something at least half-way modern like IE11.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to *literally* do what you've described.

If you're posting to a URL in the same origin (or CORS is enabled), you could do the post via `XMLHttpRequest`, use `history.pushState` to change the browser's URL to the target, and update the page's DOM with the response from the post.

But the only way to literally do what you describe is with a form, and forms can't currently send JSON.